# Facing error as Expected condition failed: waiting for alert to be present (tried for 5 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

When condition falls it goes to else, but when it is true not going in if

```
try {
    //WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);

    if(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent()) == null) {
        System.out.println("alert was not present")
        (wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/button[2]"))).click();
        Confirmation.click();
    }
    else {
        String Recipemessage = driver.switchTo().alert().getText();
        System.out.println(Recipemessage);

        if(Recipemessage.equals(alertmessage2) || Recipemessage.equals(alertmessage4) ) {

            Thread.sleep(3000);

            driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
            break;
        }
    }
} catch(Exception exp7) {
    System.out.println(exp7);
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception? If yes, please post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent()` will never return `null`, it will return the alert or throw `TimeoutException`

```
Alert alert = null;
try {
    alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
catch(Exception) { }

if(alert == null) {
    System.out.println("alert was not present")
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/button[2]"))).click();
    Confirmation.click();
}
else {
    String Recipemessage = alert.getText();
    System.out.println(Recipemessage);

    if (Recipemessage.equals(alertmessage2) || Recipemessage.equals(alertmessage4)) {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        alert.accept();
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

wait.until will wait for the time specified in WebDriverWait and throws an exception if it cannot find the alert. So instead of using it in the if condition you can do like below to find if Alert exists or not.

```
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            bool AlertExists;
            try
            {
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
                AlertExists = true;
            }
            catch
            {
                AlertExists = false;
            }
            if(AlerExists)
            {
              //do stuff
            }
            else
            {
              //do other stuff
            }
```